# R html scrape with redirect links, word searches, and counts

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to streamline a tedious process of online data collection with R scraping code. The website I am currently interested in is here : [Wisconsin Bills- Author index](https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/1997/related/author_index/assembly).

The website features a redirect link to each legislator, and then under each legislator there is a list of bills introduced, and a link to the major action summaries for each bill. My end goal is to create a data frame that includes a column for legislator name, number of assembly bills (only links that that include "AB") introduced, number of bills passed the assembly, and number of bills signed into law.

Scraping the website, I have successfully created a data frame with each legislator's first name, last name, district, state (always WI) and year (always 1999, t-1 is when the session ended). Below is my code:

```
#specify the URL
url <- "https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/1997/related/author_index/assembly"

#download the HTML code
html <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, followlocation = TRUE)

#parse the HTML code
html.parsed <- htmlTreeParse(html, useInternalNodes = T) 

# Get list of legislator names:
names <- xpathSApply(html.parsed, path="//a[contains(@href, 'authorindex')]", xmlValue)

# get all links into a list:
links <- xpathSApply(html.parsed2, "//a/@href")
# see what I have:
head(links) # still have hrefs in there
links <- as.vector(links) 
head(links) # good, hrefs are dropped.

# I only need the links that begin with /document/authorindex/1997. 
typeof(links) # confirming its character 
links # looking to see which ones to keep (only ones with "authorindex" and "A__",    where the number that follows A is the district)
links <- links[14:114] # now the links only have the legislator redirects!!!

# Lets begin to build the final data frame needed:
# first, take a look at names- there are 104, but there are only 100 legislators...
names # elements 3-103 are leg names
names <- names[3:103]

# split up by first name, last name, etc.
names <- as.vector(names)
names1 <- strsplit(names, ",")
last.names <- sapply(names1, "[[", 1) # good- create a data frame 
id = c(1:101)
df <- data.frame(ID= id)
df$last.name = last.names # now have an ID and their last name.

# now need district, party, and first names.
first_names <- strsplit(names, "p.")
first_names # now republicans have 3 elements, dems have 2, first word of 2nd element     is first name
# do another strsplit
first_names <- as.character(first_names)
first_names <- strsplit(first_names, " ()")
first_names # 4th element is almost always their name! do it that way, correct those that messed up by hand
first_names <- sapply(first_names, "[[", 4)  
first_names # 10 (Timothy), 90 (William) 80 (Joan H) 80 (Tom) 47 (John)
# 25 (Jose) 17 (Stephen) 5 (Spencer)
first_names[5] <- "Spencer"
first_names[10] <- "Timothy"
first_names[90] <- "William"
first_names[80] <- "Joan H."
first_names[81] <- "Tom"
first_names[47] <- "John"
first_names[25] <- "Jose"
first_names[17] <- "Stephen"
df$first.name <- first_names # first names- done.

# district:
district <- regmatches(names, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", names))
df$district <- district
df$state <- "WI"
df$year <- 1999
```

Now, I'm stumped. I need to follow each redirect link, and count the number of AB links under that legislator's name ONLY, follow the AB links, and count the # of AB sites for each legislator that have the word "passed" in them and the # of AB sites that have the word "Sen." in them. I would thus like to add to the existing df the following columns:

```
Bills Introduced     Bills Passed Assembly    Bills Signed into Law
4                    3                        2
39                   18                       14
```

Etc. I get the sense I need to use loops, but I don't know how to approach it.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Thank you!